# Update in ingres

Tags: sql, ingres

```
UPDATE  m
SET    m.class_code = 'new cod'
FROM   models as  m 
inner join type a on m.model_number = a.model_number
WHERE  a.type_number NOT IN ( 1, 10 )
       AND m.class_code = 'UN'
```

I have this  query  and in Ingres DB  it  doesn't  want to run. I dont  understand why. I sure it  should work in MSSQL but in Ingres its throwing an error e_us0845 table does not exist or is not owned

Comment: Hi Andrey, is this a session table? If so you can check http://community.actian.com/forum/application-development-using-openroad/15649-session-table-does-not-exist.html There is a note saying "session tables are only visible from the database session which created them, they are destroyed when the session ends"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a slight syntax error in the SQL which Paul posted.
As I'm new to stackoverflow my rep is insufficient to comment on his existing answer, so I will add this separate answer instead.

```
update models as m
from type as a
set m.class_code='new cod'
where m.model_number = a.model_number
and a.type_number not in (1,10)
and m.class_code='UN';
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ingres SQL syntax the UPDATE ... FROM expects just one or more table names in the from part, so you can't user the inner join syntax there. However since it's an inner rather than an outer join you can write it as:

```
   UPDATE  m
    SET    m.class_code = 'new cod'
    FROM   models as  m 
    WHERE  m.model_number = a.model_number
    AND a.type_number NOT IN ( 1, 10 )
    AND m.class_code = 'UN'
```

which is the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a correlation name with an update target. Change `set m.class_code='new cod'` to `set class_code='new cod'` and it will run.

Comment: The syntax is valid in Ingres. http://docs.actian.com/#page/Ing102_SQLRef%2FSQLRef_Body.1.1232.htm%23